# Вывод массива Js на страницу

Tags: javascript

Есть код, его задача - вывод отсортированного по возрастанию массива в консоль и на страницу. В консоль он выводит всё правильно, но на страницу он не выводит отсортированный массив. Помогите вывести отсортированный массив на страницу. Заранее спасибо!

```
table{
    width: 100%;
}

table td{
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.parentElem{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
#elem{
    opacity: 0;
}

</style>
<input type="button" onClick="elem.style.opacity=1;">
<div class="parentElem">
    <div id="elem"></div>
</div>
<script>


function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function compareNumbers(a, b) {//Функция для сортировки массива
  return a - b;
}

function matrixArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
  var arr = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        arr[i] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
          arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var myMatrix = matrixArray(7,5); 
myMatrix.forEach(row => row.sort(compareNumbers));//Вызов функции, которая сортирует массив по rows
console.log(myMatrix);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    var elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
    createTable(elem, 5, 7);
    function createTable(parent, cols, rows){
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML=getRandomInt(0,100);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        parent.appendChild(table);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: в каком виде его нужно выводить?

Comment: а вы никак не используете свой отсортированный массив
`td.innerHTML=getRandomInt(0,100);` где тут ваш массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто поменяйте `td.innerHTML=getRandomInt(0,100);` на `td.innerHTML=myMatrix[i][j]`

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function compareNumbers(a, b) {//Функция для сортировки массива
  return a - b;
}

function matrixArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
  var arr = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        arr[i] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
          arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var myMatrix = matrixArray(7,5); 
myMatrix.forEach(row => row.sort(compareNumbers));//Вызов функции, которая сортирует массив по rows

var elem = document.querySelector('#elem');
createTable(elem, 5, 7);
function createTable(parent, cols, rows){
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML=myMatrix[i][j]; // используем массив
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    parent.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
}

table td{
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.parentElem{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
#elem{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="elem.style.opacity=1;" value='Нажать'>
<div class="parentElem">
    <div id="elem"></div>
</div>
```